# Screen rotation issue. Screen unable to come to its original view

Tags: android

I have original screen view as:

[image]

When i press '7' key on right hand side of keboard, view becomes:

[image]

When i wanted it in my original view as shown in first image, i press '9' button of keyboard and it becomes:

[image]

What can i do to have it in my original view as shown in first image?

Please help me.

Comment: Bajirao Peshaw Press key Page up(9) or Home(7) in your number pad.

Comment: Which version of emulator are you building on? 2.3.3 or 4.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be come in regular position u just relaunched the emulator. ya as per om sai said u also try by pressing "7" key

Comment: ohh, but in my running app i can not tell user to restart the app

Comment: but it is the only problem of emulator  it will be run properly in real device

Comment: ok ok , i was unaware, i thought there must be technique to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Try this 
By again pressing to 7 key .. you will get grid in original position

Comment: by again pressing 7 its becoming like i shown in last image (with 9 button press)

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is with not pressing "7" key again.. So just pressing "7" key again and get your solution.

Comment: by again pressing 7 its becoming like i shown in last image (with 9 button press)

Answer (score 1):

**Try this By again pressing to 7 key .. you will get grid in original position of your screen**

Comment: by again pressing 7 its becoming like i shown in last image (with 9 button press)

Answer (score 1):

If you run the application in emulator, you have a chance to face this issue. Pressing 7 will help you to bring back to original position.

**If you run this on device you wont get this problem.Try running it on device**

Answer (score 1):

This is Emulator problem,Some time it happens due to system problem but here is not a concept of code because you have not written any code for landscape or portraits mode in your app.

So get this correct by:

- pressing a 7 button once more
  Or Restart your emulator